# Inserting a proof-reader's remark in a presentation title

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can I insert a word in a presentation title that looks like a proof-reader's remark. For example, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{Lorem ipsum sit amet}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I'd like to turn this into the following if possible, with a roughly cursive font (it shouldn't be too pretty).

[image]

I think it can be done with TikZ, using something like (pseudo code)

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
{
    \node at ($(current position)$) [rotate=30] {\textcolor{red}{dolor}};
}
```

The two things I haven't been able to get right are

- What to use in place of my `current position` placeholder
- How to modify the font only for the word `dolor`

Alternate approaches (or if there's a package available that does this) are also welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a quick look at the font catalogue I've found the JD font from [`emerald`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/jd/) package as a nice candidate. Then via sharp-shooting the location of the title with respect to the page center, I've added the TikZ picture also with some manual tuning. Here is the result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{emerald}
\title{Lorem ipsum sit amet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\node[rotate=55,red] (dolores) at ([shift={(6mm,2.2cm)}]current page.center) {\ECFJD dolor};
\begin{scope}[shift={([shift={(-5mm,-6mm)}]dolores.south)}]
    \draw[line cap=round,ultra thick, red,overlay] (0,0) -- ++(1mm,1mm) -- ++(0.75mm,-0.75mm);
\end{scope}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Disclaimer:* Please note that I stand between a toaster and a tablespoon in terms of IQ when it comes to dealing with fonts let alone installing them. So, it's rather a small step for mankind but a big deal for me.

Comment: This is nice, and I like the font :) Would it be possible to do the positioning a bit more relatively? I guess the use of some absolute units is unavoidable, but something like `"Lorem ipsum <anchor> sit amet"`, with `<anchor>` being invisible to the title command, but tikz is aware of it and then you can do the shifts from the `<anchor>` position. You don't have to, if it's hard/complicated; your answer is more than sufficient for my purposes :)

Comment: @yoda I forgot to mention it in the answer. This is certainly possible for regular text on a page. However, the command `\title{}` does not just hold the text itself but it is sent to various templates like the footlines etc. Hence, all kinds of trouble awaits us if we include a picture in the title command. But if you search for `tikzmark` on this site you will find the homebrewed (Andrew Stacey and Peter Grill excelled on its use) solution for putting anchors in a text or equations. It's just the title so I would stay away from such a solution.

Comment: Really nice example and nice font! I was thinking about to use the `\tikzmark` macro, but I stopped because I suspect that placed it inside the `\title` command could have lead to errors.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Ah, I forgot to mention your name among the `\tikzmark` addicts :) Maybe it is possible to use a combination of gazillion `\expandafter`s and `\noexpand`s but that would be even harder than eye-balling the location on the page.

Comment: No, no! I'm just a student on that topic :) (even if I use it very often). Anyway I agree with you: the difficulty in combining several `\expandafters` and `\noexpand`s for just one single case says that your approach win.

Comment: @percusse Ah, very good point about `\title` directing the text to footlines. I am fine with this, since I'll only be adding it after the title is finalized (and in only one location). I'll wait a bit longer to see if there are other answers before accepting yours :)

Comment: @percusse Just thinking about it, it might still be possible if one were to use the optional short title with `\title[short]{long}`, since the short one is what gets set to footlines...

Comment: @yoda I also tried a couple of different cases with that but I can't see any quick fix as it is still getting expanded in a few nasty macros. It might be an option to ask it as a new question and draw our `beamer` wizards' attention with the details we discussed here if this is going to be your usual practice.

Comment: @percusse Your answer solves my immediate need and the rest is mere idle curiosity... I don't feel comfortable making someone dig up the internals just to satisfy a stray thought (and I don't even understand the internals). Thanks though :)

Comment: @yoda Oh, please do. Many of us are craving for procrastination. A few people already know the beamer code inside out anyway :)